# Running vlc qt4 interface with Bumblebee on Debian

Tags: linux, video, debian, vlc-media-player, optimus

I am running Debian Jessie on a laptop with 2 video cards. I use Bumblebee to switch between cards. The optirun command initializes a new x server, that runs on the faster but more power consuming video card.

The problem is as follows

I run...

```
optirun vlc
```

or

```
optirun vlc --intf qt4
```

or

```
optirun vlc --intf qt4 --no-xlib
```

and vlc fails to load the qt4 interface. The vlc cli and ncurses interface do run under the optirun command, but are not as feature rich and easy to use as the qt4 interface. Any thoughts on the root of this problem?

The Bumblebee daemon log reads as follows:

```
Mar 23 16:14:38 localhost acpid: 1 client rule loaded                    [6/376]
Mar 23 16:14:38 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (WW) Unresolved symbol: fbGe
tGCPrivateKey
Mar 23 16:14:38 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to ge
t display device for DPI computation.
Mar 23 16:14:39 localhost acpid: client 13120[0:999] has disconnected
Mar 23 16:14:40 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (EE) Server terminated succe
ssfully (0). Closing log file.
Mar 23 16:14:40 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (EE) 
Mar 23 16:14:40 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (EE) Backtrace:
Mar 23 16:14:40 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (EE) 0: Xorg (xorg_backtrac$
+0x48) [0x7fdc4fb33c58]
Mar 23 16:14:40 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (EE) 1: Xorg (0x7fdc4f98c00$
+0x1ab949) [0x7fdc4fb37949]
Mar 23 16:14:40 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-g$
u/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fdc4e6f9000+0xf880) [0x7fdc4e708880]
Mar 23 16:14:40 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-g$
u/libc.so.6 (malloc_usable_size+0x26) [0x7fdc4d1b3896]
Mar 23 16:14:40 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/x86_64-lin$
x-gnu/nvidia/libGL.so.1 (0x7fdc4e916000+0xb4524) [0x7fdc4e9ca524]
Mar 23 16:14:40 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (EE) 
Mar 23 16:14:40 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (EE) Segmentation fault at $
ddress 0x0
Mar 23 16:14:40 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (EE) 
Mar 23 16:14:40 localhost bumblebeed[13089]: [XORG] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segm$
ntation fault). Server aborting
```

Comment: Did you try googling for the exact phrase "Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey"? (Use the double quotes when pasting that into the Google's search box.) It looks like there's a problem with the nVidia's proprietary blob. Hence another question: did you try this with Nouveau driver instead? (IIRC, it has good 2D accel. by unfortunately no 3D accel.)

Comment: I am able to use bumblebee to open other applications, Iceweasel for instance. I initially tried setting up the switch with the Nouveau FLOSS drivers, but failed early and gave up. Do you suppose the nVidia driver bug effects opening certain applications and not others?

Comment: Since it essentially replaces `libGL.so` with its own version, it *might* but unfortunately I don't know for sure. Do you get the warning "Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey" in the log when you *successfully* run another application under the same conditions? I'm asking because GUI toolkits other than that VLC is using might not try to resolve and call that symbol.

Comment: Comment originally from [Hadogenes](http://superuser.com/users/290517/hadogenes): Did you try: `optirun vlc --x11-display :8`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: `optirun vlc --x11-display :8`

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://superuser.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion. --- Eventually you can expand your text to explain what does the command do and why it should help to resolve the problem.

Comment: @pabouk: It’s a small world: just yesterday [studiohack♦](http://superuser.com/users/6574/studiohack) said that a “better way to accomplish this would be to flag this, asking for it to be converted to a comment - allowing for the OP to have his name migrated with it.” in [a comment](http://superuser.com/questions/907981/how-to-type-half-space-in-microsoft-onenote/909267#comment1222395_909267) to me.