# How to type half-space in Microsoft OneNote?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters, microsoft-onenote-2013, farsi

I can type a half-space on Microsoft Word using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Minus_Key</kbd>. But I don't know why it is not working on Microsoft OneNote! How can I type this character on Microsoft OneNote?

**Note:** I'm writing in Persian language. In Persian we use half-space to prevent attaching morphemes together.

Comment: *From a post by [Mr. DiBs](http://superuser.com/users/443524):* Typing (Ctrl)+(-) in Word inserts an optional hyphen; it appears only when the word needs to be split at the end of a line. See http://new.office-watch.com/2015/of-hyphens-em-dash-en-dash-and-more. If this is what you’re looking to do, I do not see a solution for this in MS OneNote 2010 or 2013. There is the possibility of an add-on that might be capable of accomplishing this. Another option is to go to the Onetastic website and request a new feature or macro. Omer Atay has done a great job in helping the OneNote community.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got my answer! If we use [Persian Standard Keyboard **(FAS)**](https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%88%DB%8C%DA%A9%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%D9%BE%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%A7:%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B3%DB%8C), we can type half-space with <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>. We can't use Default Persian Keyboard (FA) to write half-space in OneNote. FAS already exists on Microsoft **Windows 8 or greater**. You can install this keyboard from [this link](http://persian-computing.org/download/Iranian_Standard_Persian_Keyboard_(ISIRI_9147)_(Version_2.0).zip) for previous versions of Microsoft Windows.

Comment: I have Windows 10 (version 1706) and **shift+space** does not create a ZWNJ on the Persian Keyboard, but **CTRL+shift+2** works.

Comment: Windows Persian Standard Keyboard swaps many key's position which is hard to get used to.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are not into Persian Standard Keyboard (FAS) due to it's unexpected keys swapping and also the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> sounds odd to them (like me!), [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) is a life saver.

1. Download & Install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com).
2. Go to `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder via windows explorer<sup>1</sup>.
3. Create a file with a desired name but .ahk extension
4. Edit the file via right clicking on and add the following line in it:<sup>2</sup> <sub>[ref](https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%87_%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B2%DB%8C)</sub>

   ```
   +Space::Send {ASC 0157}
   ```
5. Save & run the script.

<sup><sup>1</sup> This makes the script run on every windows startup</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> As in FAS keyboard (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>), Otherwise it could be whatever you want.</sup>

---

**Update**: a complete script based on current keyboard layout could be found as [a specific repo on Github](https://github.com/Mostafa-Armandi/AutoHotKeyScripts/blob/master/PersianHalfSpace).

Answer (score 1):

Note sure what version of OneNote you are using.  Oops! missed tags sorry.

If you are using MS OneNote 2010 here list of shortcut keys at link below.
http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/onenote_2010.html

For MS OneNote 2013 try the link below.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-OneNote-2013-65dc79fa-de36-4ca0-9a6e-dfe7f3452ff8?CorrelationId=caf32e2a-1f4d-4351-b2ca-b8808669586b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find my answer in your links. Please guide me if I'm in mistake

Answer (score 1):

***"I can type a half-space on Microsoft Word using Ctrl + Minus_Key. But I don't know why it is not working on Microsoft OneNote! How can I type this character on Microsoft OneNote?"***

Typing Ctrl + –  (Ctrl and hyphen) inserts an optional hyphen.  In this example each word has an optional hyphen after the letter ‘c’ so it only appears when the word needs to be split at the end of a line.

From Office Watch  http://new.office-watch.com/2015/of-hyphens-em-dash-en-dash-and-more/

If this is what you're looking to do, at the present time I do not see a solution for this in MS OneNote 2010 or 2013.  There is the possibility of an add-on that might be capable of accomplishing this.  Another option is to go to the [Onetastic website](http://omeratay.com/onetastic/) and request a new feature or macro. Omer Atay has done a great job in helping the OneNote community.

If I come across anything I will let you know. 
Good luck with your endeavors.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.  To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).  Since you do not have that privilege yet, I have reposted your answer as a comment (trimmed to fit within the limit of 600 characters).

Comment: @G-Man: better way to accomplish this would be to flag this, asking for it to be converted to a comment - allowing for the OP to have his name migrated with it. I appreciate your effort to keep his post/info around - it is tricky to keep some answers within 600 chars. As for this particular post, I'm undecided as how relevant it is and will leave it for now. Thanks!

Comment: @studiohack: I considered that. What would you (or whatever moderator) have done with an answer larger than 600 characters if I flagged it that way?

Comment: @G-Man: mods can edit comments actually - so one of us would probably have converted it, and then copy/pasted from the answer, then edited. Cheers!

Comment: OK, I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily type half-space using **Ctrl + Shift + 2** in Microsoft office, when you are using Persian (Farsi) keyboard.